# RestKit upload image parameters

Tags: ios, image, spring, upload, restkit

I have to configure server side for uploading image with RestKit 0.2 using a Spring.

I use the following code for uploading:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] multipartFormRequestWithObject:obj
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                          path:nil
                                                                                    parameters:nil
                                                                     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {


    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(obj.image, 1.0)
                                name:@"image"
                            fileName:@"image.jpg"
                            mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

}];



RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                                 success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                                                                                                     NSLog(@"%@", [mappingResult firstObject]);

                                                                                                 } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                                                                                 }];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

My WS side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "findMatch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void findMatch(@RequestParam(value = "image") Part image){

    // ...
}
```

When i try to upload the image I get the error: **The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**

My question is, what is the name of the image parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the server accept a 'list' of images?

Comment: The server accept one parameter called "image", what did you mean with "list"?

Comment: If the server can take multiple images you may need to set the name to `image[0]`

Comment: The server can't take multiple images, I just want a single image, and I don't known the param name of the image, in other words what I have to put into the @RequestParam.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "findMatch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void findMatch(HttpServletRequest request){

     MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
     MultipartFile multipartFile = multipartRequest.getFile("image");

     // handle file...
}
```